# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B NRF24L01 Pin Connections

Tags: pi-2, arduino

I'm trying to connect Arduino Nano and Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. But there is a problem that I really couldn't handle for more than 10 hours. When i try to ping out from Raspberry Pi, it says "Check your wires." But i really tried many options for it. And i couldn't find the true one.

Here is the pins of NRF24L01 :
[image]

I connect GND to GND, VCC to 3.3V, CE to CE0, CSN to CE1, SCK to SCLK, MOSI to MOSI and MISO to MISO. IRQ cable is free now cause in web sites that i looked for says its free.

And here is the output when i try to ping out.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
/* 
2015-04-06 : Johan Boeckx - Arduino/RPi(2) nRF24L01+ : Raspberry Pi (2) code 
  Tested on Arduino UNO R3 and Raspberry Pi B Rev. 2.0 and Raspberry Pi 2 B 

 Copyright (C) 2011 J. Coliz <maniacbug@ymail.com> 

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or 
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License 
version 2 as published by the Free Software Foundation. 

 03/17/2013 : Charles-Henri Hallard (http://hallard.me) 
              Modified to use with Arduipi board http://hallard.me/arduipi 
                          Changed to use modified bcm2835 and RF24 library 
TMRh20 2014 - Updated to work with optimized RF24 Arduino library 

*/  

#include <cstdlib>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <sstream>  
#include <string>  
#include <RF24/RF24.h>  

using namespace std;  
//  
// Hardware configuration  
// Configure the appropriate pins for your connections  

/****************** Raspberry Pi ***********************/  

// Radio CE Pin, CSN Pin, SPI Speed  
// See http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__constants.html#ga63c029bd6500167152db4e57736d0939 and the related enumerations for pin information.  

// Setup for GPIO 22 CE and CE0 CSN with SPI Speed @ 4Mhz  
//RF24 radio(RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_22, BCM2835_SPI_CS0, BCM2835_SPI_SPEED_4MHZ);  

// NEW: Setup for RPi B+  
//RF24 radio(RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_15,RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_24, BCM2835_SPI_SPEED_8MHZ);  

// Setup for GPIO 15 CE and CE0 CSN with SPI Speed @ 8Mhz  
//RF24 radio(RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_15, RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_24, BCM2835_SPI_SPEED_8MHZ);  

// RPi generic:  
RF24 radio(22,0);  

/*** RPi Alternate ***/  
//Note: Specify SPI BUS 0 or 1 instead of CS pin number.  
// See http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html for more information on usage  

//RPi Alternate, with MRAA  
//RF24 radio(15,0);  

//RPi Alternate, with SPIDEV - Note: Edit RF24/arch/BBB/spi.cpp and  set 'this->device = "/dev/spidev0.0";;' or as listed in /dev  
//RF24 radio(22,0);  


/****************** Linux (BBB,x86,etc) ***********************/  

// See http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/pages.html for more information on usage  
// See http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/ for more information on MRAA  
// See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev for more information on SPIDEV  

// Setup for ARM(Linux) devices like BBB using spidev (default is "/dev/spidev1.0" )  
//RF24 radio(115,0);  

//BBB Alternate, with mraa  
// CE pin = (Header P9, Pin 13) = 59 = 13 + 46  
//Note: Specify SPI BUS 0 or 1 instead of CS pin number.  
//RF24 radio(59,0);  

/********** User Config *********/  
// Assign a unique identifier for this node, 0 or 1  
// 0 Rx / 1 Tx  
bool radioNumber = 0;  
unsigned long timeoutPeriod = 3000;     // Set a user-defined timeout period. With auto-retransmit set to (15,15) retransmission will take up to 60ms and as little as 7.5ms with it set to (1,15).  

/********************************/  

// Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.  
// const uint8_t pipes[][6] = {"1Node","2Node"};  
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xABCDABCD71LL, 0x544d52687CLL };   // Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.  
char data[32] = {"_A message from RPi w/ NRF24L+!"};            //Data buffer  

void showData(void)  
{  
      printf("Data: ");  
      for(int i=0; i<32; i++){  
         if(isprint(data[i]))  
           printf("%c", data[i]);  
         else  
           printf(".");  
      }  
      printf("\n\r");  
}  

int main(int argc, char** argv){  

  const int role_rx=0, role_tx=1;  
  int role=role_rx;  
/********* Role chooser ***********/  

  printf("\n ************ Role Setup ***********\n");  
  string input = "";  
  char myChar = {0};  

  cout << "Choose a role: Enter 0 for Rx, 1 for Tx (CTRL+C to exit) \n>";  
  getline(cin,input);  

  if(input.length() == 1) {  
    myChar = input[0];  
    if(myChar == '0'){  
        cout << "Role: Rx " << endl << endl;  
    }else{  cout << "Role: Tx " << endl << endl;  
        role = role_tx;  
    }  
  }  
  switch(role) {  
      case role_rx :  
        radioNumber=0;  
        break;  

      case role_tx :  
        radioNumber=1;  
        break;  
  }  

/***********************************/  
  // Setup and configure rf radio  
  radio.begin();  

  // optionally, increase the delay between retries & # of retries  
  radio.setRetries(15,15);  
  // Set the channel  
  radio.setChannel(1);  
  // Set the data rate  
  //radio.setDataRate(RF24_2MBPS);  
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);  
  //radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);  
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);  

    if ( !radioNumber )    {  
        radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);  
        radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);  
        memset(&data,'\0',sizeof(data));  
        radio.startListening();  
    } else {  
        radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);  
        radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);  
        radio.stopListening();  
    }  
    // Dump the configuration of the rf unit for debugging  
    radio.printDetails();  
    printf("Start loop:\n");  
    // forever loop  
    while (1)  
    {  
        if (radioNumber) {  
            if (radio.writeBlocking(&data,sizeof(data),timeoutPeriod)) {  
                printf(".");  
            }  
            else {  
                printf("?");  
            }  
            fflush(stdout);  
            //printf("\n");  
        }  
        else {  
        //  
        // Receive each packet, dump it  
        //  
            if(radio.available()){  
                // Read any available payloads for analysis  
                radio.read(&data,32);  
                // Dump the printable data of the payload  
                showData();  
                fflush(stdout);  
            }  
        }  
        delay(5);  
    } // forever loop  

  return 0;  
}
```

Code is not mine. I found it on internet.

As i said, i tried many ways. And i'm really stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Here is the web site i looked for. I made the steps that wrote there and successed.

http://thedigitalryan.com/index.php/2015/05/24/raspberry-pi-2-and-arduino-with-nrf24l01-radios/